# ng-change event not working first time, seleted toggle button to unselect

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have used toggle buttons to select multiple records. I have display existing records with selected, at the first time when click on toggle button to uncheck, in that case ng-change event not working. second time click on same toggle button to select, ng-change is working properly...

```
var unitsLists = [{Id:1, UnitType:'Kg'}...];
var selectedUnits = [1,2,...]; //existing unit ids array
```

Please suggest me to fix this issue...

```
<ion-list>
<ion-toggle ng-repeat="item in unitsLists" ng-checked="selectedUnits.indexOf(item.Id) != -1" ng-true-value="{{item.Id}}" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="UnitListModel[item.Id+item.UnitType]" ng-change="setToggleValue(UnitListModel[item.Id+item.UnitType], item.Id);" toggle-class="toggle-balanced">
                <h2>{{item.UnitType}}</h2>
            </ion-toggle>
            <a ng-hide="unitsLists.length > 0" class="item item-icon-right clsCenter">Record not found.</a>
        </ion-list>
```

Comment: put setToggleValue() method code..!

Comment: Please check methods

$scope.setToggleValue = function (val, id) {       
        var index = $scope.selectedUnits.indexOf(id);
        if (val > 0 && index === -1) {
            $scope.selectedUnits.push(id);
        } else if (val == 'false' && index != -1) {
            $scope.selectedUnits.splice(index, 1);
        } else if (val == false && index != -1) {
            $scope.selectedUnits.splice(index, 1);
        }       
    }

Comment: ng-model is not getting set...!u can check with ng-click..!

Comment: ng-click event working..  Thanks....  but first time model value showing undefined

Comment: I have used this in controller, working ng-change and receiving value...
Is there any other solutions to fix..

 $filter("filter")(responce, function (val, key) {
                if ($scope.selectedUnits.indexOf(val.Id) === -1) {
                    $scope.UnitListModel[val.Id + val.UnitType] = false;
                } else {
                    $scope.UnitListModel[val.Id + val.UnitType] = val.Id;
                }
            }, false);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i have changed lot from ur code and its working!but hope this will help u..!just try

in controller:

```
 $scope.unitsLists = [{Id:1, UnitType:'unit1'},
  {Id:2, UnitType:'unit2'},
  {Id:3, UnitType:'unit3'},
  {Id:4, UnitType:'unit4'},
  {Id:5, UnitType:'unit5'}];

$scope.selectedUnits = [1,3]; //existing unit ids array

$scope.UnitListModel = {};
angular.forEach($scope.selectedUnits, function(value, key) {
  $scope.UnitListModel[value] = 'true';
});
$scope.setToggleValue = function (id) {
  var index = $scope.selectedUnits.indexOf(id);
  if ( index === -1) {
    $scope.selectedUnits.push(id);
    $scope.UnitListModel[id] = 'true';
  } else if (index != -1) {
    $scope.selectedUnits.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.UnitListModel[id] = 'false';
  }
  console.log("$scope.selectedUnits :"+JSON.stringify($scope.selectedUnits));
  console.log("$scope.UnitListModel :"+JSON.stringify($scope.UnitListModel));
}
```

html :

```
<ion-toggle ng-repeat="item in unitsLists"
                ng-checked="selectedUnits.indexOf(item.Id) != -1"
                ng-model="UnitListModel[item.Id]"
                ng-click="setToggleValue(item.Id);"
                toggle-class="toggle-balanced">
     <h2>{{item.UnitType}}</h2>
</ion-toggle>
```

u can add `ng-true-value="{{item.Id}}" ng-false-value="false"`

Comment: Its great solution, thanks a lot.... but there is as issue... If Unit Id is 1, 200, 250, 4000 in that case "UnitListModel" model is creating array like that.. 0, 1, null, null, null... 200, null,.. 250, null, null.... upto 4000, therefore its creating issue...